# How to list my application when you try to open a PDF in email?

Tags: ios, ios4, pdf-reader

I wanted to list my application in the list of other readers installed in the iphone when I try to open the PDF from the email. What settings do I need to do on my project so that my application is also listed in it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [Implementing Support for Custom File Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW12)?

> Applications that are able to
>   open specific document or file formats
>   may register those formats with the
>   system. When the system or another
>   application needs to open a file, it
>   can hand that file off to your
>   application to do so. In order to
>   support custom file formats, your
>   application must:
>
> - Register the file types your
>     application supports with the system.
> - Implement the proper methods to open
>     files (when asked to do so by the
>     system).